# Link two tables that have transposed rows and columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say there is a table of products:

```
product    | description <<COLUMN NAMES
productA   | dec1
productB   | dec2
productC   | dec3
```

and a table of customer data:

```
Customer    | zipcode <<COLUMN NAMES
customer1   | 12345
customer2   | 23456
customer3   | 34567
```

and a table of product ratings by customer:

```
product    | customer1 | customer2 | customer3 <<COLUMN NAMES
productA   |  1        | 3         | 5  
productB   |  2        | 2         | 4
productC   |  3        | 4         | 3
```

I can link (foreign key) the table of products to the table of product ratings by customer by "product".

How do I link (foreign key) the table of customer data to the table of product ratings by customer by "customer"?

Comment: what's that you're trying to get? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: your 'product rating by customer' table has 4 columns ( product, customer1, customer2, customer3)? If it's the case, you might want to redesign your table the following columns `(product, customer, rating)` assuming product and customer are foreign keys.

Comment: Yes, I edited the question clarifying the column names of the tables

Comment: The ratings table is a horrible design. It means you need to change the schema every time you get a new customer.

Comment: Yes, follow @Tin's advice and re-design your table schema. What happens when you have ratings from four customers (or 10 or 1000)? Read/watch some tutorials on relational database design and normalization. Also, don't feel stupid. Everybody is a beginner at the beginning :)

Comment: In general, anything that's likely to change frequently should be in the data, not the schema.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. Tin's suggestion was what I could not get my head around as a database newbie.